# Android: how do I do the opposite of 'Matrix.mapPoints(float[] points)'?

Tags: android, matrix, game-engine

If I have a point and a Matrix:

```
float point[] = new float[]{x,y};
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
```

and call:

```
matrix.mapPoints(point);
```

how could I reverse the effects that `matrix.mapPoints(point)` has on `point`?

This isn't the actual application that I will use the answer for, but an answer for this will would work for what I need.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't want `yourMatrix` to change

```
 Matrix inverseCopy = new Matrix();
 if(yourMatrix.invert(inverseCopy)){
      inverseCopy.mapPoints(transformedPoint);
      //Now transformedPoint is reverted to original state.
 }
```

If you want `yourMatrix` to change

```
 if(yourMatrix.invert(yourMatrix)){
      yourMatrix.mapPoints(transformedPoint);
      //Now transformedPoint is reverted to original state.
 }
```

`matrix.invert()` returns `false` if the `matrix` cannot be inverted. If your `matrix` cannot be inverted there is no way to revert your points to original state.

Comment: The second part of the answer is wrong, `yourMatrix.invert(null)` results in a `NullPointerException`. We need to pass a matrix in which the inverse will be stored.